# Issues with running an instrumentation test in Android Studio; Didn't find class "android.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, android-espresso

I'm trying to run a test case in android studio that should open the navigation drawer, click a menu item, and check if it navigated to that item.

When I try to run the test I get the following error

```
Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
Empty test suite.
```

Logcat shows;

```
-02-04 13:41:17.703 10121-10121/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.damhan.dublinbusassist, PID: 10121
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.damhan.dublinbusassist.test/android.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" on path: DexPathList...
```

Here is my test case:

```
package com.damhan.dublinbusassist;

import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.view.Gravity;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.contrib.DrawerActions.open;
import static android.support.test.espresso.contrib.DrawerMatchers.isClosed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.contrib.NavigationViewActions.navigateTo;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class NavigationDrawerTest {
    @Test
    public void clickRouteNavigationItem_ShowsRouteScreen() {
        // Open Drawer to click on navigation.
        onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout))
                .check(matches(isClosed(Gravity.LEFT))) // Left Drawer should be closed.
                .perform(open()); // Open Drawer

        onView(withId(R.id.nav_view))
                .perform(navigateTo(R.id.route_menu));


        String expectedNoStatisticsText = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
                .getString(R.string.routePageText);
        onView(withId(R.id.route_menu)).check(matches(withText(expectedNoStatisticsText)));
    }
}
```

And my build.grade is as follows;

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.damhan.dublinbusassist"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.0.2'

}
```

I'm very new to writing test cases so I realise there is likely going errors and I have taken from the sample google android-testing github so some of the things may be currently named incorrectly but I would expect it to at least run!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`. Notice `support` part

Comment: Silly mistake on my behalf, apologies for the time wasted.